# OSX - start-up alias in bash not working. Stored in /etc/profile, /etc/bashrc, ~/.bash_profile

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I want to store the directory where Bear Notes keeps its database so I can easily access it. I'm backing it up on github. I know I should probably automate it, but I want to solve this problem first.

OSX version 10.12.6

I've added the line

```
bearUrl=~/Library/Group Containers/9K33E3U3T4.net.shinyfrog.bear/Application Data
```

to the FIRST line of my `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` files, yet `echo $bearUrl` proves the alias hasn't been saved (returns nothing).

Does anyone know why this isn't persisting and where I should be saving this value instead?

Comment: do you see any `command not found` error when starting a new shell?

Comment: `Containers/9K33E3U3T4.net.shinyfrog.bear/Application: No such file or directory`

Thanks for pointing that out, made the mortal sin of not escaping a space when pasting the path in.

Which file of the three is standard for adding an alias btw?

Comment: Aliases are a feature of interactive shells, so ~/.bashrc is where those go. See [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in the manual.

Comment: @TheThing : While glenn jackman is right with his comments, we should also point out that you do **not** define any alias with your code. Aliases are defined using the `alias` command.